# For loops in R (time to time intervals)

Tags: r, time

I would like to convert my data (times) into respective time interval by using R language. My dataframe is as shown below:

```
Date,Time,Lots,Status
"10-28-15","00:04:13","13-09","1"
"10-28-15","00:04:16","13-10","1"
"10-28-15","00:04:30","13-11","1"
"10-28-15","00:04:44","13-12","1"
"10-28-15","00:04:48","13-13","1"
"10-28-15","00:04:50","13-14","1"
"10-28-15","00:04:57","13-15","0"
"10-28-15","00:04:57","13-16","0"
"10-28-15","00:05:04","13-17","0"
"10-28-15","00:05:04","13-18","0"
```

And I would like to have output of intervals like this(with 4 intervals hourly/ each 15 mins)

```
Date,Time,Lots,Status,*interval*
"10-28-15","00:04:13","13-09","1",*"00:04:00"*
"10-28-15","00:04:16","13-10","1","00"04"15"
"10-28-15","00:04:30","13-11","1","00:04:30"
"10-28-15","00:04:44","13-12","1","00:04:45"
"10-28-15","00:04:48","13-13","1","00:04:45"
"10-28-15","00:04:50","13-14","1","00:04:45"
"10-28-15","00:04:57","13-15","0","00:04:45"
"10-28-15","00:04:57","13-16","0","00:04:45"
"10-28-15","00:05:04","13-17","0","00:05:00"
"10-28-15","00:05:04","13-18","0","00:05:00"
```

If i'm using for loop, such as

```
for(i=0,i<=60,i+15)
} for(if(i>i && i<=i+15)
}
```

How can i do it in R language? Thanks for the help guys, newbie in programming..

```
sample$int<- strptime(paste(sample$V1,sample$V2),format="%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S")
min_V2<-trunc(min(strptime("28-10-2015 00:00:20", "%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S")),"min")
max_V2<-trunc(max(strptime("28-10-2015 23:59:59", "%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S")),"min") + 900
out <- cut(sample$int, breaks = seq(min_V2, max_V2, by = "15 min"))
```

Comment: `cut` can be used with date/time objects too. What's the `str` of your data?

Comment: hi @AnandaMahto. Thanks for replying. I have seen cut function but i'm not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you meant *seconds*, not *minutes* in your description of what you wanted.

Here's a basic example of how we can go from your input data to 15-second intervals:

First, convert your "Date" and "Time" columns to form an actual date/time object:

```
x <- strptime(paste(mydf$Date, mydf$Time), 
              format = "%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S")
```

Second, find out what the minimum and maximum values in your range of values are. Since it seems that these values are from the same day, but with variable minutes, I picked "min" to truncate at. For the `max` value, I added 60 seconds to round up to the next minute.

```
min_x <- trunc(min(x), "min")
max_x <- trunc(max(x), "min") + 60
```

Third, we can use `seq` to create a sequence of breakpoints by every 15 seconds. We can use those breakpoints in `cut`:

```
out <- cut(x, breaks = seq(min_x, max_x, by = "15 sec"))
out
#  [1] 2015-10-28 00:04:00 2015-10-28 00:04:15 2015-10-28 00:04:30
#  [4] 2015-10-28 00:04:30 2015-10-28 00:04:45 2015-10-28 00:04:45
#  [7] 2015-10-28 00:04:45 2015-10-28 00:04:45 2015-10-28 00:05:00
# [10] 2015-10-28 00:05:00
# 8 Levels: 2015-10-28 00:04:00 ... 2015-10-28 00:05:45
```

Fourth, if you are only interested in the time interval, you can reformat the output of `cut` as a date/time object, and use `format` to extract just the hour/minute/second portion.

```
format(as.POSIXct(out), "%H:%M:%S")
#  [1] "00:04:00" "00:04:15" "00:04:30" "00:04:30" "00:04:45" "00:04:45"
#  [7] "00:04:45" "00:04:45" "00:05:00" "00:05:00"
```

Comment: thanks @Ananda Mahto. it seems like the min and max generating errors as its output is NA

Comment: @SiewmeiLoh, I explained how you can use `trunc` in my answer. You will need to adjust according to your actual data.

Comment: Sorry i still don't get it. do i need to change the "min" argument to function call? appreaciate if you could show me an example... say, my minimum is 0.

Comment: @SiewmeiLoh, the "min" argument should be the minimum date you expect to be working with, at the minimum time-interval you want to report. For example, here your actual minimum date/time is "28 Oct 2015, 00:04:13". Since you are interested in breaking this into 15 second chunks starting at 0 seconds, we can reasonably set the min in this case to be `strptime("28-10-2015 00:04:00", "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")`. Similarly, your max could be theoretically set as `strptime("28-10-2015 00:05:15", "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")` since there is no value in your sample dataset higher than that.

Comment: I was trying to change part of the date format, the codes end up showing error as the min became NA. Appreciate if you could tel me what's wrong with the code as i couldn't find any. thanks. the code is editted into post above.